# Unity URP Invert desaturated shader effect with

Tags: unity, shaders, scene, masking

I wanted to have a shader that invert and desaturate the background scene color with a mask in URP using scene color.
[image: explanation of the shader renderings]

I made a shader within shadergraph :
[image: Shadergraph invert filter]

And it did not render as expected, I think it does not render transparent but I'm not quite sure, for instance the image below showcase both shader with a tmpro text behind.
I found this [shader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69719893/7334912) where the invert effect works but it doesn't have any mask properties. How can I apply a mask onto it ? Or is there a reason the shadergraph don't work with the scene color ?

Here are both rendering:
[image: Shaders view]

Working on Unity 2020.3.25f1 and URP 10.7

EDIT:

I managed to make this shaders implementation, it invert following the mask but doesn't give the desaturated look:

```
Shader "Unlit/invert_Mask"
{
    Properties 
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader 
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent" }
        Cull off

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        AlphaToMask On


        Blend OneMinusDstColor Zero
        AlphaToMask On

        Pass 
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 3.0 Alpha:Blend

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            bool invertMask;
            
            fixed4 _Color;
            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }
        
            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col;
                col.rgb = _Color;
                col.a = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                return col;

            }

            ENDCG

        }

    


    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```